# Java | Pass caret through regex

Tags: java, regex, replace, caret

I'm making a method that needs to replace all "^"'s, with " ^ ". But I'm using `.replaceAll()`, and that takes in a regular expression as a parameter, and the caret (`^`) means *not* or *everything but* in regex. There's not even an escape character for it.

So how do I do it?

```
String a = "8^2";

public static String magicMethod(String a) {
    return a.replaceAll("^", " ^ "); // makes everything compile funny
}
```

Comment: You should be able to escape the carat with `\\^`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can escape all special regex characters using a backslash (`\`). Since backslash is also a Java String literal escape character, you have to double it when writing as a Java String.

```
a.replaceAll("\\^", " ^ ")
```

If you want to use `replaceAll()` and the search string and/or replacement value is a plain text, you can have the strings automatically escaped for you.

```
a.replaceAll(Pattern.quote("^"), Matcher.quoteReplacement(" ^ "))
```

This is generally only used when the search string and/or replacement value is dynamic. When constant, as in your case, escape using backslash.

Answer (score 2):

You need unescape `^`

```
return a.replaceAll("\\^", " ^ "); // makes everything compile funny
```

The `^` in regex means the start of String